# Optimal solution for: Keeping state of entity in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

### Problem

When I design structure of a database, I often work with tables that can have a state assigned. For example a *response* for an *offer* - this *response* table can, for instance, have these states:

1. waiting - response was created and waits for approval by owner of offer
2. cancelled - response was cancelled by its author
3. approved - response was approved by the author of *offer*
4. rejected - response was rejected by the author of *offer*
5. expired - response expired together with associated *offer*

### I am considering these two solutions

#### 1. Solution

Create table *response_state* and keep its key in the *response* table as foreign key

- Pros:

  - All states are together in one table
  - New state can be added easily
- Cons:

  - Synchronization of *response_state* foreign key value with other response's columns is necessary. For example, for expiration - when expiration day is reached, state has to be changed to "expired".

#### 2. Solution

Put approved/rejected/cancelled logical value columns into *response* and create view *view_response_state* that will contain a column with state name according to values in these columns and the expiration date.

For example, if approved is false, rejected is false, cancelled is false and expiration_date < today, then state is "waiting" etc.

- Pros:

  - No synchronization needed, all data are kept once in the db
- Cons:

  - When I want to add a new state I have to change table *response* and provide *view_response_state* with logic of identification of such state

### Question

My question is, which approach would you choose? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Solution #2 has "all data are kept in the db"; in what way is this not true of Solution #1?  Don't you have to change *response* table to add a new state for both solutions?  Couldn't you have logic similar to what you have for Solution #2 in Solution #1, but keyed off the state codes instead of boolean columns?

Comment: It is difficult to understand solution 2 to be fair. To make a decision try to implement CRUD code for both and compare.

Comment: Solution #1 is the standard implementation (assuming that you mean `response_state` to be used as a reference table).

Comment: @Scott Hunter: you missed word "once" In solution 1 there is a duplicity

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Thank you, but with #1 I have to deal with duplicity - i have to add some additional logic which changes state to "expired" after expiration date is reached. Is that correct?

Comment: @Michal: Do you mean "duplication"?  I don't see what is duplicated.  ("Duplicity" means deception.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you need three tables.

One is to be called "response_state".  It contains five rows, one for each of your response names. If you need to add a new response name, just INSERT it to this table. It has the column "response_state_id."  Little tables like this are often called codelist tables.

Another is to be called "offer".  It will have an offer_id and other information as needed about the offer.

The third is "response."  It contains the following columns.

```
response_id          pk, autoincrement
offer_id             fk to offer table
response_state_id    fk to response_state table
response_timestamp
(other columns relating to the response as needed)
```

This table works as follows: Anytime the state of a response changes, you INSERT a row to this table showing the new state. You never UPDATE these rows. You might DELETE old ones in a purge process for completed transactions.

When you need to find the current state of an offer you give a query like this. It pulls only the *most recent response* to each offer from the table.

```
SELECT r.offer_id, r.response_state_id, rs.response_state_name
  FROM response AS r
  JOIN response_state AS rs ON r.response_state_id = rs.response_state_id
  JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(response_id) as latest_id,
                 offer_id
            FROM resp
           GROUP BY offer_id
        ) AS recent ON r.response_id = resp.latest_id
```

This is a really cool way to handle this because it retains the history of responses to each offer. Because it's an INSERT-only solution it's inherently robust against various kinds of race conditions if lots of responses come in on top of each other.